# How do I continue to show changes (via sidebar color bars) in MPLAB X IDE after git commit?

Tags: git, mplab, mplab-x

How can I set MPLAB X to continue to show the colored change bars that appear on the main editor sidebar (furthest right, next to the vertical scrollbar) after a git commit? I would like to be able to toggle this on/off (i.e., select no diff branch, or a compare branch).
I can get close by using Tools > git > diff, and selecting which branches I want to compare, but I want to be able to see this is the main editor panel, not the diff panel. I find it useful at times to still see what has changed.